# Do not inflict any serious injury to me

Tags: выражения

What expression do you use to say

Do not inflict any serious injury to me.

It would be the same as

Don't hurt me.

However, what I would like to say is not 
some thing like,

Stop poking me. It hurts. Stop hurting me.

But rather, in situations like I am being mugged in the corner of the street.

I see you have got a barbed club and a knife. You are mugging me. 
I will give you my money but
Don't hurt me.

Comment: Are you going to visit Russia? :)

Comment: @Ivan: http://i.imgur.com/8oQO9LQ.jpg

Comment: Yes, I have already been to Vladivostok and I want to visit again but I hope I never have to use these phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mugging**

Не бейте меня.

Не бейте меня, я отдам вам деньги. / Я отдам вам деньги, [только] не бейте меня.

Не бейте меня, я отдам вам то, что вам нужно.

Не бейте меня, я отдам вам то, что вы хотите.

Не бейте меня, я отдам вам куртку (камеру, фотоаппарат).

that is all, other is redundant.

**In the school**

Хватит тыкать меня. Больно же!

Хватит тыкать меня ручкой (линейкой, циркулем).

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest translation would be *не причиняй мне вреда* or *не делай мне вреда*, though it sounds kinda too legalese for a situation like that.

One would rather use *не бей меня* "don't hit me", *не режь меня* "don't stab me", *не трогай меня* "don't touch me" or *ничего мне не делай* "don't do anything (bad) to me".